# Including c++ lib to xcode cocoa project

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I am trying to include a C++ library to my Cocoa app.

I added a Bridging-Header.h to my app. It has

```
#import FooLib/Foo.h
```

FooLib/Foo.h has

```
#if defined (__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

    #include "base/bar.h"

#if defined (__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

base/bar.h has

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <set>
#include <string>
...
```

xcode errors says:  'set' file not found

I am on 10.12 with xcode 8.

Build Settings has

```
> Apple LLVM 8.0 - Language - C++ C++ Language Dialect
> GNU++11[-std=gnu++11] C++ Standard Library libc++
```

Did I forget to load something?

Maybe because xcode is not using a C++ compiler? Any clue where I can verify/setup that?